# How to connect kafka to external server.ip

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I have Kafka set up on my local machine, and I'm using `github.com/segmentio/kafka-go` to implement consumer producer model and working fine with localhost.
But wanted to connect to an external server that is running on EC2.

```
ip:= X_XXX_XXX_XXX

    func CreateTopic() {
        _, err := kafka.DialLeader(context.Background(), "tcp", "ip:9092", "indicator", 0)
        if err != nil {
    
            fmt.Println("error in creating topic: " + err.Error())
        }
    
    }
    
    func ListofTopics() {
        conn, err := kafka.Dial("tcp", "ip:9092")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        defer conn.Close()
    
        partitions, err := conn.ReadPartitions()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        
    
        m := map[string]struct{}{}
    
        for _, p := range partitions {
            m[p.Topic] = struct{}{}
        }
        for k := range m {
            fmt.Println(k)
        }
    }
```

when executing **createTopic() function** getting error like **host not found or connection refussed** and gone through some article to reslove this issue. but it was not usefull.

Made chanage to **server.properties** file like

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
```

and modified like this too

1. In **config/server.properties:**

> advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://X_X_X_X_X:9092

2. In **config/producer.properties:**

> bootstrap.servers=X_X_X_X_X:9092

and added  to **sudo nano /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.ap-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

But still getting connection refused error and not host found if proerties file revered back.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/356598/why-cant-i-reach-my-amazon-ec2-instance-via-its-elastic-ip-address

Comment: 1) `config/producer.properties` is used for Java client code, not the server, or Go 2) You shouldn't need to edit the hosts file; this is a routing table issue, not DNS 3) You put ap-east in the hosts file, but us-east in your server properties 4) listeners should bind to 0.0.0.0:9092 or all open interfaces, not to a hostname